# Test firefox in a loop

Tags: bash, firefox

I would like to simply bash the following: start firefox, test it, kill its process if it does not work and restart it; or stop the script once for all if it works.

Actually I need a `awk` sentence to intercept string "ESTA      http" from netstat and put $CONDTION to 0.

```
#!/bin/bash
$CONDITION=1;
while($CONDITION)

firefox & timeout 10s watch -n 1 'netstat -a | grep "http    ESTA"|$CONDITION=0; (<-bad syntax)

if [$CONDITION == 0]; 
    then break
fi

kill $(ps aux | grep 'firefox' | awk '{print $2}');

done;

exit;
```

Comment: this is not perl. just do `CONDITION=0` instead of adding a `$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

URL='http://www.google.com/'

while true; do
    firefox "$URL" & sleep 10
    netstat -anp | grep -m 1 ':80 .*/firefox' && exit
    killall firefox
done
```

Comment: pkill firefox would work as well, but ya, looks good to me.